# ASP.Net MVC4 Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having this issue that keeps flagging up and I have checked every file. Just want to see if anyone else can spot an error?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Event List";
}

<div>

Event Name : @Model.item.eventname <br />
Event Date : @Model.item.date <br />
Event Town : @Model.item.town <br />
Event Country : @Model.item.country <br />
Event Description : @Model.item.description <br />
Event Report : @Model.item.report <br />

@Html.ActionLink("Add New Event" , "AddEvent")


 @*Html.Partial("EventList")*@

</div>
```

All reply's are much appreciated !

Bellow is the Event Model which is linked to the orginal post:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NETCW.Models
{
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event name.")]
    public string eventname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event date.")]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event town.")]
    public string town { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event country.")]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event description.")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event report.")]
    public string report { get; set; }

}
}
```

See bellow edited I am getting a error it says it does not contain a definition for the following Date, Town, Country and Report :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NETCW.Models
{
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event name.")]
    [Display (Name = "Event Name :")]
    public string eventname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event date.")]
    [Display (Date = "Event Date :")]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event town.")]
    [Display (Town = "Event Town :")]
    public string town { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event country.")]
    [Display (Country = "Event Country :")]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event description.")]
    [Display (Description = "Event Description :")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the event report.")]
    [Display (Report = "Event Report :")]
    public string report { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is null?

Comment: item is most likely null.  Have you checked it at runtime while debugging to ensure that it is not null?

Comment: Show the error details. Check if property `item` is `null`

Comment: Check the link for the photo for error

http://snag.gy/GuHI3.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not declared you model in the view. At the top of the view you need to declare it

```
@model NETCW.Models.Event
```

**Edit**

Based on the edited question `@Model.item.eventname` will also fail because `Event` does not contain a property named `item`. In addition you need to pass the model to the view, and you should be using the htlm helpers to generate the elements. In the GET method

```
Event model = new Event();
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.eventname)
```

and if your property is decorated with `[Display(Name = "Event Name:")]` then you can use the following to generate the associated label

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.eventname)
```

Comment: When you say YourAssembly you mean like:

   @model NETCW.Models.Event

Comment: You have not posted you model, but yes, something like that

Comment: That error is because the model is `null`. In the GET method, you need to return the model - e.g. `var model = new Event(); return View(model);`. And use the html helpers to generate your elements.

Comment: I have uploaded the Model of Events in the orginal post

Comment: What problems are you still having?

Comment: Not sure exactly where it needs to go. Was wondering If I was able to send the Project across if you was able to have a quick skim. If possible

Comment: Sorry, but no. You need to include the details in your question (SO is for helping other users as well). What is the **it** in _"Not sure exactly where **it** needs to go"_?. I'm not sure which bit you do not understand, or what problems your still having

Comment: I have uploaded the main parts of the files onto the original comment. Hope this helps in finding the problem?

Comment: You still haven't said what the problems is! But now you have changed the model in the view to `@model IEnumerable<NETCW.Models.Event>` but you GET method only returns  a single `Event` because you use `LastOrDefault()` - the `@foreach (var item in Model) {` loop would throw an exception. And you appear to have repeated the same view code twice.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Which controller method is the second view you have shown associated with?

Comment: Still Having the same error flag up as before after changes

Comment: In which view? See my last 2 comments - your edit does make sense so hard to understand what the issue is.

Comment: I have made changes to the original post to make it clearer to understand. Hopefully this makes it clearer to understand how it is running

Comment: Now you have  completely changed the question making my answer a complete waste of time and useless to anyone. My answer was correct for your original question (I even tested it) but I assume you wont be accepting it so I'll delete this shortly. Good luck getting future help.

Comment: Sorry Stephen I really want to get this to work but not sure where to exactly implement the changes

Comment: Thanks for your solution I have implemented most if it. I am just wondering where you are entering the [Display (eventname = "Event Name :")]

Comment: I see you have rolled back your edits :). Its actually `[Display(Name = "Event Name:")]` and its just an attribute added to you model property (in the same way you have added the [`Required]` attribute. Then when you use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.eventname)` it will output `"Event Name:"` instead of `"eventname"`

Comment: It needs to be `[Display (Name = "Event Date :")]` and `[Display (Name = "Event Town :")]` etc (the `DisplayAttribute` has a property `Name`, not `Date` or `Town`)

Comment: That should be self explanatory - You have declared `@model NETCW.Models.Event` but you have passed `IEnumerable<NETCW.Models.Event>` to the view in the controller method. We are getting off track now and this thread is getting to long. If you have further problems, please ask a new question with the relevant code for model, controller and view (but keep it to a minimum - no need to include every property)

Comment: Fixed the problem now ! :) Only problem is that it is not displaying the entered list

Comment: Are there any items in the list? Are the properties of the each items set? You will need to debug your code.

Comment: Debugging has come back fine So I can enter items http://snag.gy/Zz3Qy.jpg but it will then not Display it on the page http://snag.gy/ASyew.jpg... I think it is being directed to the wrong page or something is missing

Comment: It appears you have not saved the new `Event` to your repository, therefore when you redirect to the method that displays the collection, its empty (you need to debug all your code). I'm sorry, but you need to create a new question with the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Much appreciated... I need to wait 3 days before I can ask another question :(

Comment: I see that your 2 previous questions were both down voted. Spend some time reading the help files to learn how to ask better questions that wont be down voted (then the question limit will be removed - see [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)